# Find highest number using if statement in a for loop java

Tags: java, if-statement, for-loop

Ok I am a little stuck with a question I found online. I need to write a class which works out the *watts* as the *resistor* goes up by one i.e the *resistor* starts at `1` and every for loop `1 ohm` is added to it: `1 ohm` then `2 ohm` then `3 ohm` etc etc.

I have done all that: there are 3 resistors in total and 2 of them have preset Ohms. Now I need to cycle through that 9 times.

I have the calculations all worked out and I am getting the output for it. The question gives you some information and a print out. Now I need to make my print out look the same.

I have the for loop working but now I need to use a if statement to find the highest watts and say at how many Ohms the resistor was that had the total.

I am not asking for a direct answer to the problem but more a point in the right direction if at all possible.

In advance I would like to thank anyone that has helped me.

```
public class Question51 
 {
    public static void main(String[] args) 
   {
      double Vs = 12, V1, V2, V3, I1, I2, I3, R1 = 10, R2 = 15, R3 = 1, Rpar, PowerInR3;        

      for(R3 = 1; R3 <= 9; R3++)
      {
        Rpar = (R2 * R3)/(R2 + R3);
        I1 = Vs/(R1 + Rpar);
        V1 = I1 * R1;
        V2 = Vs - V1;
        I2 = V2 / R2;
        I3 = V2 / R3;
        PowerInR3 = V2 * I3;

        System.out.println("When r3 = "+R3+" Ohms, Power in R3 = "+PowerInR3+" watts.");
      }     
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should declare a `max` variable and initialize it with some very low value. For example `Double.MIN_VALUE`.

Then in every iteration of the loop you could update your maximum like this:

```
max = Math.max(max, valueYouWantToCompare);
```

Finding the correct Java syntax is your task now :-) Good luck!

Comment: Thanks a million for the help mate. Am off to the java library to have a look. This has been wrecking my head for the last two days.

Answer (score 1):

You need to do the following:

- Assume max power as min to min value and create another variable to hold maxResistance.
- In your for loop, use if to check whatever was the last value of maxPower is greater than power generated by current resistance. If that's the case change your assumption saying this could be max and loop with next resistance value.

  ```
  public class Question51 
  {
      public static void main(String[] args) 
      {
           double Vs = 12, V1, V2, V3, I1, I2, I3, R1 = 10, R2 = 15, R3 = 1, Rpar, PowerInR3; 
           double maxResister = 0, maxPower = Double.MIN_VALUE;       

           for(R3 = 1; R3 <= 9; R3++)
           {
               Rpar = (R2 * R3)/(R2 + R3);
               I1 = Vs/(R1 + Rpar);
               V1 = I1 * R1;
               V2 = Vs - V1;
               I2 = V2 / R2;
               I3 = V2 / R3;
               PowerInR3 = V2 * I3;

               if (maxPower < PowerInR3) {
                   maxPower = PowerInR3;
                  maxResister = R3;
               }

               System.out.println("When r3 = "+R3+" Ohms, Power in R3 = "+PowerInR3+" watts.");
           }
           System.out.println("Max Power when Resistance is " + maxResister + " ohms is " + maxPower + " watts");
       }
   }
  ```

Comment: `"I am not asking for a direct answer to the problem"`.

Comment: Thanks for the help mate as of yet I have not actually read through it. If I really can't work out the solution in the next day or so I will make sure that I reference it and figure out where I am going wrong. Thanks again.